# Voting System Button Fix

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, performance

I have this website where people can up vote or down vote certain businesses. The voting system uses PHP, MySQL, Javascript and AJAX to function. When a vote is made, the user's IP is put into a database and remembered so they cannot vote again. However, it is possible to use an auto clicker program and set it to click faster than the server can process the voting request, which results in this: http://mcserve.rs/qSmn

I already tried using Javascript to hide/disable the button when clicked until the AJAX request finishes, but that is still too slow.

How can I fix this, or is it fixable at all?

Thanks

EDIT: I know that someone using an auto clicker is a very small percentage but doing so could exploit the entire purpose of the website - I am looking for a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Um, you do not need a webpage to submit to your page so fixing it on the client does not fix the issue.

Comment: It seems he wants to prevent the autoclickers...

Comment: As long as no duplicate votes are registered by the DB, I don't see any point in this. Once the auto-clicking guy refreshes the page he'll see the counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a key constraint of the IP field in the database table that stores the vote information, you don't need to worry about auto clickers, since for each IP there is at most one row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be taking you that long to process a voting request and you can just block off POST requests from the same client to the upvote URL directly on the server. A much better option would be just to use a login system, but, that must not be an option...

Comment: I have considered that - if there is no way to do it via the browser, then I will most likely to that

Comment: You cannot do it through the browser. The client has nothing to do with security on the server. I could write a script to fire POST requests towards your server and all your Javascript code would be of no relevance whatsoever. This is a server issue, not a client one.